# Print 1D of 2D Array on Sheet

Tags: arrays, excel, vba

I'm having issues printing a simple array in range Range("H" & i & ":H" & (i + size). Here is the relevant code snippet:

```
'print on the sheet
size = 1 + UBound(arrPartList)
Rows((i + 1) & ":" & (i + size)).Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
        
For Each item In arrPartList
Debug.Print item
Next item
        
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NewRelease").Range("H" & i & ":H" & (i + size)) = arrPartList '<--desired line
ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NewRelease").Range("H" & i & ":l" & (i + size)) = arrPartList '<--For testing only
```

So with the debug.print I get the perfect 5 values I am expecting:
3124105-01
3124101-01
3124104-01
3124103-01
3124102-01

But I get the same number, the first one that prints in all 5 cells of the H range.
So I tried expanding the range from H to M to see what would print and indeed there are my values horizontal.Looks like this:
[image]

How do I fix this? Now worth finding the problem with the array, I refer just doing the print differently in this code snippet.
I want exactly the 5 values from the debug.print window in my selected H range.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: `... = Application.Transpose(arrPartList)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to transfer values from sheet to array and from array to sheet.

```
Sub TestAndTry()

    Dim Rng         As Range
    Dim arrPartList As Variant
    Dim R           As Long                 ' row

    With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("NewRelease")
        Set Rng = .Range(.Cells(1, "H"), .Cells(5, "H"))    ' "H" = columns(8)
        arrPartList = Rng.Value
        
        R = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "H").End(xlUp).Row + 1      ' next free row
        Set Rng = .Range(Rows(R), Rows(R + UBound(arrPartList) - 1))
        Rng.Insert Shift:=xlDown, CopyOrigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    
'        For R = 1 To UBound(arrPartList)
'            Debug.Print arrPartList(R, 1)
'        Next R
    
        Set Rng = .Cells(R, "H").Resize(UBound(arrPartList), UBound(arrPartList, 2))
        Rng.Value = arrPartList
    End With
End Sub
```

Key to understanding this code is in realising that when you copy a range to an array, a 2D array is created, even if the range has only one row or column. The array has the rows in its first dimension and the columns in the second. Note that Ubound(Arr) equals Ubound(Arr, 1) but for Ubound(Arr, 2) the 2 can't be omitted. Both bounds are 1-based.

When you paste an array to a sheet the size of the receiving range must match the array exactly in rows and columns. That's easy to achieve because Ubound gives the number of rows and Ubound, 2 the number of columns. So, you specify a starting cell and use the `Resize` method to extend the range to the size of the array. Demonstrated in the above code.

Comment: @Chris Neilson Thank you. I was indeed struggling for words at that point.